# Windows 7 Dual Boot Hibernation

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, multi-boot, hibernate

I have two different editions of Windows 7 installed on two different partitions (on the same physical drive).  One is Windows 7 Professional 32-bit, one is Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

I have both because I use some applications that are compatible/work better on one or the other, so I find myself switching between the two quite often.  My question: is it possible to hibernate from both operating systems to make swapping between them faster?  Rebooting every time I need to switch from 32-bit or 64-bit is cumbersome and I wish I could just hibernate and swap quickly.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to hibernate both OSes and just resuming each separately? If so, that is possible and makes this question a duplicate:

[Is it possible to enable hibernation when dual booting Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/46299/24500)

> I think you can do this if you install both Windows versions on different physical volumes and then use the boot device selection of your BIOS to choose the one or the other. On my computer this can be entered by hitting F11 at system boot.

---

If you are trying to **share a hibernation file between two OSes, then that is impossible**.

Comment: I don't have them on two different physical volumes, only two different partitions.  Of course, I intend for the hibernations to be completely separate, but when I hibernate one and reboot it skips the OS selection and immediately resumes the most recently hibernated OS.