# How to have both OSs hibernated

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, boot, hibernate

I set up a dual boot with Windows 7 and Windows 8, it all works good, I can hibernate each w/o problems. Now I find annoying that every time I want to go to the other OS I have to shut down the system I'm currently using... is it possible to hibernate one OS and then, turning on the PC, to boot up the other? Going even further, is it possible to hibernate even the second one and then, at the boot, have the usual choice between which OS to boot up/wake up?
I'd very like to do so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to enable hibernation when dual booting Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/46299/), [Windows 7 Dual Boot Hibernation](http://superuser.com/questions/377548/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. That's by design.

Imagine you're converting a movie, running Win7.
Then you hibernate the OS.
When you boot it again, the conversion continues where it left.

If you would be able to boot a different OS, you could delete the target file. That would cause serious problems when you would boot the Win7 again. -- This is just a hint to the range of possible problems.

Comment: While your examples are decent, they don't prove that this behaviour is by design. Could you provide a source for this?

Comment: I can't provide an official link for windows, this post: http://askubuntu.com/a/145904/7745 provides the same reasoning -- it was just easier for me to find.

Comment: just a sidenote: running linux, it's still possible to *read* from a filesystem of a hibernated windows.